# Error while saving excel file after updating value

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-2007

I am using Excel Interop library for reading and writing excel sheet.When i try to write and save workbook by `Save()` method it gives,

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Although `Saveas()` and `SaveCopyAs()` method works fine.I want to update same file used for read. Below is my code:-

```
 excelApplication = new Excel.Application();
                        excelApplication.DisplayAlerts = false;
                        // excelApplication.ScreenUpdating = true;
                        excelApplication.Visible = false;
                        excelWorkbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(filePath,
                        Type.Missing, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                        true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCorruptLoad.xlExtractData);

                        dict = new Dictionary<string, Excel.Worksheet>();

                        foreach (Excel.Worksheet worksheet in excelWorkbook.Worksheets)
                        {
                            dict.Add(worksheet.Name, worksheet);
                            Excel.Worksheet sheet = dict[worksheet.Name];
                        }
                        Excel.Worksheet sheetobj = dict["Risk Register"];
                         //sheetobj.Cells[10, 4]
                        ((Excel.Range)sheetobj.Cells[10, 4]).Value2 =123;

                        excelWorkbook.Save();
```

Comment: can set the two `true` value inside the Open() to `false' and check..if it solve i will post ans with details

Comment: problem still persist with same exception..

Comment: do u have write option for the specific path?

Comment: No,I want to update or write same file at same path.

Comment: yes thats why you r using Save() i understand..but do u have write permission to that particular folder

Comment: yes..because SaveCopyAs() method is working..

Comment: can u post the SaveAs() u used to save the excel? because if SaveAs() is doing with same path it will replace the existing one with the data entered..